# Why does Django say there is no module named views?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that I wrote. I am testing it on the development server. It is saying that there is no module named views, even though the file views.py is one level higher than it in the directory views. Why is this? Does the views.py need to be in the same folder as the urls.py? Is that causing this?

Comment: Can you share your exact directory structure? Typically, views.py and urls.py are stored in each respective app's folder.

Comment: Note that "views" is not a reserved word and you can change what module/file/function a url points to however you like.  Take some time and go through the django tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they should be in the same folder.
You can check the directory structure here -
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 1):

The views.py must be in the same folder as in the urls.py. If not, while importing the views.py, its better to specify the exact path of the views.py, from the SYS_PATH of the project (from the folder where you have the manage.py file), which will help